# How to plot graph with letter xtics which have more values in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have data

```
A 45
B 446
A 565
A 789
C 456
C 464
B 465
```

where first column is xtics and second ytics. I would like to plot it with points where several y values belong to one x value. How to match it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a standard scatter plot and `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = list("ABAACCB")
b = [45, 446, 565, 789, 456, 464, 465]
plt.scatter(a,b)
```

[image]

Comment: if you want to distinguish points, you could add color parameter, like so `colors=['red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'] `  and then `plt.scatter(a, b, color=colors)` or some version of it

Comment: how do you want the points to be connected? in the order you have them in that data frame? just have `plt.plot(a,b)` after the `plt.scatter(a,b)`

Comment: Thank you. I created two lists - a like [4G6 8R8 4G6] = a and b = [5 6.8 4.1]? `ValueError: a and b must be the same size` How to solve that please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245450/how-to-use-strings-as-xvalues